# Drupal 8 custom type content, getting values for a field of type Taxonomy (hence, Entity Reference), which can have multiple values in the field

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

I have a custom content type (we'll call it '**book**')... and it has a field  (We'll call the field '**category**') which is of type *Taxonomy Term* and which **can hold say ten items**.

I can load the content programmatically:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','custom content type machine name')->execute();

        $nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

I can then scroll through the items of node using something like

```
  foreach ($node as $node_item){
      echo $node_item->title
   }
```

However, how would I output the content of the **reference entity** 'category' ... say if category has 3 items assigned to it, it would be something like this:

```
  foreach ($node as $node_item){
      echo $node_item->title,
      echo $node_item->category[0]->target_id,
      echo $node_item->category[1]->target_id,
      echo $node_item->category[2]->target_id,
   }
```

But, this does not work...

There is the suggestion that $node_item->category has to be loaded as an entity reference but using $node->cateogry->referenceEntities () does not load anything.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $node_item->category->referencedEntities() is what you want to use.

You have misspelled the method in your question.

```
 if ($node_item->category->isEmpty() === FALSE) {
    $vars = [];
    // Get referenced entities and add each to array of terms.
    foreach ($node_item->category->referencedEntities() as $term) {
      $vars[] = [
        'name' => $term->label(),
        'phone' => $term->field_phone_number->value,
        'email' => $term->field_email_address->value,
      ];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks oknate that did the trick ... thanks for taking the time to help